# Notifying specific client after posting to server in Xamarin

Tags: c#, asp.net, xamarin

I'm creating a messaging module for an existing web application using Xamarin. This application connects to a legacy Firebird database via a web API of our own (standard ASP.NET app hosted in IIS). In my module, I have, say, *user1* and *user2*. Whenever *user1* sends a message to *user2*, my Xamarin app will post that message to a route in the API, which in turn will persist it to the Firebird database.

Surprisingly, that wasn't too hard to accomplish, but now I'm stuck because for the life of me, I can't figure out how to notify *user2* from the server so I can refresh his UI whenever a new message is sent to him. Is there any way to do this, from this *stateless* context while avoiding creating a new table in the Firebird database? I've been searching for hours, but every solution I came up so far falls flat because I don't have a list of devices readily available whenever the API is running.

This is how I send messages from the Xamarin app:

```
public async static Task<ResultModel> SaveMessage(MessageModel model)
{
    return await DependencyService.Get<IApiCall>().PostAsync<ResultModel, MessageModel>("messages/add", model);
}
```

And this is the API code that handles it:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("messages/add")]
public IHttpActionResult AddMessage()
{
    dynamic postData = JObject.Parse(Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
    var message = new Message
    {
        SenderId = postData.SenderId,
        ReceiverId = postData.ReceiverId,
        TimeStamp = postData.TimeStamp,
        Body = postData.Body
    };

    try
    {
        IRepository repository = new Repository();
        repository.Add(message);
        repository.Save();

        // With additional parameters sent from the client-side, I could send data to/notify the Receiver from here

        return Ok(new { Result = new ResultModel() });
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        return Ok(new { Result = new ResultModel(true, e.Message) });
    }
}
```

Take a look at the commentary in the code above. If I posted more data to the server, I probably could come up with some way to send notification data to the receiving end ("*user2*") at that point, avoiding having to deal with the database, but this is where I stutter as I don't see any kind of data *user1* could have about *user2* to make this work.

Any help will be appreciated.

**UPDATE:** I came across SignalR and I'm taking a look at it. It seems there's still hope after all.

Comment: Are the clients all web clients? Or Android apps? Or a mixture? Anything else?

Comment: I'm sorry if I haven't made myself clear enough, all clients are Xamarin apps, fortunately there is no mixture here.

Comment: How about push notifications then?

Comment: Do you want to notify user when app is closed or when app is already running?

Comment: I wanna notify them while the app is running. In fact I want to refresh their UI should a message be sent and should they be looking at that specific sender's message list. Basically like whatsapp or any other messenger does. I'm cooking a Thread/Task-based solution right now to query the server for changes in a regular interval, but I think I might just be creating a bottleneck in the end

Comment: It sounds like you need to use push notifications. Google's firebase will allow you to send a message from a server to a mobile device (or from one device to another but I wouldn't recommend that).  https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/

Comment: I've read about them, but all samples seem to deal with azure and in this case, I'm stuck with a legacy database. Regardless, I just found out about SignalR and that might just do the trick. Let's say push notifications  are my last line of defense right now

Answer (score 0):

Should anyone come across this question **before** learning about SignalR (which is very unlikey), the answer is simple as that: https://www.asp.net/signalr